# How do I render/display an excel table with gwidgets2 gdf widget. I keep getting Default Visible <- method is not implemented

Tags: r, dataframe, render, gwidgets

I have tried show and visible but can not get the data frame to render in the widget.   I have verified that the there is data in the table via the print statement. I am unable to change the visibility of the container to render the table.  I am getting the following error message:

```
Default visible <- method is not implemented
```

```
library(openxlsx2)
library(gWidgets2)
library(gWidgets2tcltk)
library(dplyr)

# Initialize global variables
file_path <- NULL
wb <- NULL
combined_data <- list()
selected_table_data <- NULL
selected_table_name <- NULL # To store the selected table name

# Get Sheet and table names and named ranges from Excel workbook
file_path <- file.choose()
wb <- openxlsx2::wb_load(file_path)
sheet_names <- openxlsx2::wb_get_sheet_names(wb)
sheet_dfs <- lapply(sheet_names, function(x) openxlsx2::wb_get_tables(wb, sheet = x))
combined_data <- bind_rows(sheet_dfs, .id = "sheet_name")

# Create the main window
w <- gwindow("Select a Table to Export to CSV", visible = FALSE)

# Create a label for reporting period selection
glabel("Select Reporting Period:", container = w)

# Create a main box container for controls within the main window
main_controls_box <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container = w)

# Create a sub box container for the table selection controls
table_controls_box <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container = main_controls_box)

# Create a gcombobox for table selection
tab_name <- gcombobox(
  items = sort(unique(combined_data$tab_name)),
  cont = table_controls_box,
  label = "Table Name",
  expand = TRUE,
  selected = 1
)

# Add a handler for gcombobox selection changes
addHandlerChanged(tab_name, handler = function(h, ...) {
  selected_table_name <<- svalue(tab_name) # Store the selected table name
  
  # Show or hide the gdf based on selection
  if (!is.null(selected_table_name)) {
    visible(selected_table) <- TRUE
  } else {
    visible(selected_table) <- FALSE
  }
})

# Create a sub box container for the calendar picker
calendar_controls_box <- ggroup(horizontal = FALSE, container = main_controls_box)

# Create a date input widget for reporting period using GCalendar
reporting_period <- gcalendar(
  text = "",
  format = "%Y-%m-%d",
  container = calendar_controls_box
)

# Create a "Load" button
load_table_btn <- gbutton("Load", cont = main_controls_box, handler = function(h, ...) {
  load_selected_table()
})

# Create a gdf (gDataframe) to display the selected table
selected_table <- gdf(
  cont = main_controls_box,
  expand = TRUE,
  text = "",
  widgetOptions = list(
    header = TRUE
  ),
  visible = TRUE # Render the gdf widget by default
)

# Function to look up and load the selected table
load_selected_table <- function() {
  if (is.null(selected_table_name)) {
    gmessage("Please select a table first.")
    return()
  }
  
  selected_row <- which(combined_data$tab_name == selected_table_name)
  selected_sheet_name <- combined_data$sheet_name[selected_row]
  selected_table_ref <- combined_data$tab_ref[selected_row]
  
  # Use selected_sheet_name and selected_table_ref to read the table
  selected_table_data <<- openxlsx2::wb_to_df(wb, sheet = selected_sheet_name, dims = selected_table_ref, col_names = TRUE)
  
  # Update the gdf to display the selected table
  svalue(selected_table) <- selected_table_data # Assign the data
  
  # Show the selected_table
  visible(selected_table) <- TRUE
}

# Make the main window visible
visible(w) <- TRUE

# Run the GUI event loop
while (TRUE) {
  if (!validObject(w)) { # Check if the gwindow is valid
    break
  }
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
}
```